# Sort alphabets in a word/string

Tags: excel, vba

Does excel vba have a function to sort a given word or string alphabetically? Also, what is this kind of a string manipulation called in technical/programming terms?

```
For e.g. Word = "Somestring"
Output = "egimnorSst"
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/3/24/applying-an-alphabetical-sort-to-your-vba-array-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the question itself is very minimal I would like to answer nonetheless. If you not bothered having `S` and `s` reversed than:

```
Sub Test()

Dim x As Long
Dim str As String: str = "Somestring"

With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For x = 1 To Len(str)
        .Add Mid(str, x, 1)
        .Sort
    Next
    Debug.Print Join(.Toarray, "")
End With

End Sub
```

Results in:

```
egimnorsSt
```

---

If that is not what you want it becomes a bit more complicated I think since we cannot use ASCII codes (`S` = 83 and way lower than the other characters).

It may not be super pretty but try:

```
Sub Test()

Dim x As Long
Dim str As String, str_new As String

str = "abcdABCD"
With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For x = 1 To Len(str)
        .Add Mid(str, x, 1)
        .Sort
    Next
    str_new = Join(.Toarray, "")
End With

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "([a-z])\1+"
    If .Test(str_new) Then
        For Each Match In .Execute(str_new)
            str_new = Replace(str_new, Match, Application.Proper(Match)) 'Assuming no more than 1 of the same uppercase letters.
        Next
    End If
End With
Debug.Print str_new

End Sub
```

Results in:

```
AaBbCcDd
```

---

Another option if you have ExcelO365 with new DA-functions and value in `A1`:

```
=CONCAT(SORT(MID(A1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)))
```

This would actually return `egimnorSst`

Comment: Thanks JvdV and @Ron Rosenfeld, I actually managed to write a VBA code to convert the string to and array and then sort it, similar to what you both have suggested, but I'll also try out the formula, because thats something that I was actually looking out for. Much appreciated.

Comment: Friendly hint: don't forget the "$" when applying the formula to following rows: `'=CONCAT(SORT(MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)))` :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you have Excel O365 with the functions I've used below, you can use this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(,,SORT(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))
```

or as indicated by @JvdV, instead of `TEXTJOIN` we can use the simpler:

```
=CONCAT(SORT(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))
```

[image]

If y0u don't have those functions, you would need a UDF written in VBA.

Here is one that, since the sort strings should be relatively short, uses a simple Bubblesort to sort the string elements.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Function sortString(S As String) As String
    Dim str() As String
    Dim I As Long

ReDim str(1 To Len(S))
For I = 1 To Len(S)
    str(I) = Mid(S, I, 1)
Next I

BubbleSort str

sortString = Join(str, "")

End Function

Sub BubbleSort(TempArray)
'copied directly from support.microsoft.com
    Dim temp As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim NoExchanges As Integer

    ' Loop until no more "exchanges" are made.
    Do
        NoExchanges = True

        ' Loop through each element in the array.
        For I = LBound(TempArray) To UBound(TempArray) - 1

            ' If the element is greater than the element
            ' following it, exchange the two elements.
            If TempArray(I) > TempArray(I + 1) Then
                NoExchanges = False
                temp = TempArray(I)
                TempArray(I) = TempArray(I + 1)
                TempArray(I + 1) = temp
            End If
        Next I
    Loop While Not (NoExchanges)
End Sub
```

Comment: @JvdV Thanks for pointing that out. I had tested it in a different cell, then changed it for posting, but copied the wrong one.

Comment: @JvdV And I never think of `CONCAT`, even when it is appropriate.